# how can i have two different object rotating at the same time in a multiplayer game with photon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am currently working on a 2D game in unity using photon for the multiplayer, the player has a gun object that points to the mouse position, however when two people are in a game the object will point to their mouse on their end, even if the other player is holding the gun.
thanks

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class gunRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool nf;
    bool f;
    bool l = true;

    void Start()
    {
    }

    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //rotates the gun
        Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        float rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        difference.Normalize();
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotationZ);

        if (rotationZ < -90 || rotationZ > 90)
        {
            if (gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y == 0)
            {
                transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(180, 0, -rotationZ);
            }
            else if (gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y == 180)
            {
                transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(180, 180, -rotationZ);
            }
        }
        // helps gun switch pos
        if (gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y == 0 && l == true)
        {
            nf = true;
            l = false;
        }


        // switch gun pos
        if (gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y == 0 && nf == true)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x + 1.123f, gameObject.transform.position.y, gameObject.transform.position.z);
            nf = false;
            f = true;
        }
        else if (gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y == 180 && f == true)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x - 1.123f, gameObject.transform.position.y, gameObject.transform.position.z);
            f = false;
            nf = true;
        }
    }


   
    
}
```

Comment: Please clarify requirements. Does only one player have the gun? To who's cursor should it point? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Your FixedUpdate code is running for all instances with this script attached.  If player 2 gets spawned in, player 1 will control both on their end, and player 2 will control both on their end.  The solution is to use IsMine checks to determine if this player should be controlling the script.  `if (photonView.IsMine) { .. do code }`

Comment: i have tried to do photon view but it seems to not let the gun rotate at all